# Inner join with multiple conditions across multiple tables (SQL)

Tags: sql

Looking for advice regarding combining multiple SQL queries into a multi-part inner join statement.

I have the following three tables (**Table**: Columns):

- **VisitTable**: pid, visit_date, visit_start_datetime, visit_end_datetime, visit_id, visit_type, visit_length, visit_rating
- **CondTable**: pid, cond_date, cond_datetime, cond_id, cond_type, cond_length, cond_rating
- **ProdTable**: pid, prod_id, prod_date, prod_start_datetime, prod_end_datetime, prod_rating, prod_price

I have the following atomic SQL queries:

```
select pid, visit_date, visit_start_datetime, visit_end_datetime
from VisitTable
where visit_id = XYZ AND visit_start_datetime > '01/01/2009'

select pid, cond_date, cond_datetime
from CondTable
where cond_id in (ABC, DEF, GHI)

select pid, prod_date, prod_start_datetime, prod_end_datetime
from ProdTable
where prod_id in (123, 456, 789)
```

Let's call the result of the first query (`Temp1`), the second query (`Temp2`), and the third query (`Temp3`).

I'd like to inner join `Temp1` with `Temp2` on `pid` where (`Temp1.visit_start_datetime <= Temp2.cond_datetime <= Temp1.visit_end_datetime`), i.e. in the case where `Temp2.cond_datetime` is in range `[Temp1.visit_start_datetime, Temp1.visit_end_datetime]` for that `pid`. Let's call the result of this join `Temp4`.

I would then like to take this result (`Temp4`) and inner join it with `Temp3` on `pid` where `Temp3.prod_start_datetime` is in range `[Temp1.visit_start_datetime, Temp1.visit_end_datetime]`.

Questions:

1. How can I do this using 1 SQL query with multiple inner joins and conditions?

I've tried the following syntax but it's not correct:

```
select pid, visit_date, visit_start_datetime, visit_end_datetime
from VisitTable
where visit_id = XYZ AND visit_start_datetime > '01/01/2009'
left join
    (select pid, cond_date, cond_datetime
     from CondTable
     where cond_id in (ABC, DEF, GHI)) Temp2 on Temp2.pid = VisitTable.pid
where Temp2.cond_datetime between VisitTable.visit_start_datetime and VisitTable.visit_end_datetime
left join
    (select pid, prod_date, prod_start_datetime, prod_end_datetime
     from ProdTable
     where prod_id in (123, 456, 789)) Temp3 on Temp3.pid = VisitTable.pid
where Temp3.prod_start_datetime between VisitTable.visit_start_datetime and VisitTable.visit_end_datetime
```

2. In the first atomic SQL query, I originally tried using a `WHERE` clause with `visit_date` but got an error saying "visit_date" is an integer. I then tried using `visit_start_datetime` and it accepted the condition `>= '01/01/2009'`. Why does this happen and is there anyway I can use `visit_date` instead?
3. After I construct this query, how can I then group by date and count the number of entries that appear for each date?

Thank you!

Comment: Edited to add question #3 - group by date and count.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following SQL, your date is not formatted in a way that can be understood by the SQL queries.

```
select Temp1.* from
(
select pid, visit_date, visit_start_datetime, visit_end_datetime
from VisitTable
where visit_id = XYZ AND visit_start_datetime > '2009-01-01'
) as Temp1 inner join
(
select pid, cond_date, cond_datetime
from CondTable
where cond_id in (ABC, DEF, GHI)
) as Temp2 on Temp1.pid = Temp2.pid
and Temp1.visit_start_datetime <= Temp2.cond_datetime and Temp2.cond_datetime <= Temp1.visit_end_datetime
inner join
(
select pid, prod_date, prod_start_datetime, prod_end_datetime
from ProdTable
where prod_id in (123, 456, 789)
) as Temp3 on Temp1.pid = Temp3.pid
and Temp1.visit_start_datetime <= Temp3.prod_start_datetime and Temp3.prod_start_datetime <= Temp1.visit_end_datetime
```

Comment: Thank you @Vlam!  The `visit_start_datetime` column actually works using both your suggestion of '2009-01-01' as well as '01/01/2009'. However, trying to use `visit_date` instead of `visit_start_datetime` will not work.  Using the query that you constructed, how would I go about grouping by date and counting the number of entries that appear for each date?

Comment: When you said it will not work, are you saying it's not returning any values or wrong values? Is visit_date using the same datatype as visit_start_datetime? What datatype are you using in both of those columns?

Comment: Actually just returns an error saying `visit_date` is an int.  And yes the datatype is different for both of these columns. `visit_start_datetime` is a datetime, while `visit_date` is an int.

Comment: You can't compare an int with a datetime. If you can convert the visit_date into a datetime then the query should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, will do that! Thanks.  Any advice regarding the group and count by date?

Comment: Replace `Temp1.*` with `Temp1.visit_date, count(*) as numofentries` and at the end add `group by Temp1.visit_date`.